# Question title is not updated after revisions

Tags: bug, editing

There is some strange behaviour I noticed in this question.  [How much The Square is Swedish and Danish?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85055/48608) . Its title is not updated after the revisions by user.

In [revision 3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/85055/3), @AnkitSharma edited the title and the body of the question. An hour later, @Paulie_D made further edits in the body in [revision 4](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/85055/4). There was no modification to the title.  Yet, the outcome after the edit kept the tile of [revision 2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/85055/2).

Following is the screenshot of all the  revisions made to the question.

[image: The revisions page of the question]

Why did this happen?

Comment: I have a recollection of a conflicting edit when I was doing mine so perhaps that was it.

Comment: @Paulie_D May be not. There was 1 hour gap between revision 3 and 4.